# What's wrong with my ajax function for fetching images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I’m polling S3 every 5 seconds for an image. My polling is successful and I can see it GETs the URL with the image in web inspector. But the function inside of the done() isn’t executing (I can't see anything logging to console):

```
  (function poll() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      userId = $('#photo').data('user-id');
      photoPath = $('#photo').data('photo-path');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/user-photos/'+userId+'/original/'+photoPath,
        done: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          $("#photo").append(data);
        },
        complete: poll
      });
    }, 5000);
  })();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you think `$("#photo").append(data)` will show the image?

Comment: `setTimeout` makes it once with delay of 5 seconds , you need `setInterval` to make it every 5 seconds

Comment: @MajedDH if you look, the function is being called in done() - this is the correct way because the image may take a short time to load and eventually setInterval will interfere with its previous iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for `dataType: 'json'` but you won't get that back because the server is sending an image.

Are you wanting to show the image in `$('#photo')`?

```
 (function poll() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('polling');
      userId = $('#photo').data('user-id');
      photoPath = $('#photo').data('photo-path');
      $('<img>').on('load', function(){
          $('#photo').empty().append(this);
          poll();
      }).prop('src', 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/user-photos/'+userId+'/original/'+photoPath);
    }, 5000);
  })();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aLZFP/) (with image path replaced by jsfiddle logo)